# Unable to get data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I'm running MongoDB 3.2.16.
I have created a username and password for my database.
I can access database through my desktop client (robomongo), but when I set my connection string like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:pass123@localhost:27017/dbname');
```

on the server, nothing happened.

Can you please tell me if there are additional options?

Comment: You're not doing anything? what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @KevinSmith This is just one line on server.js file. I am trying to get some data with GET request. Server worked fine without authorization.

Comment: can you capture the error? `mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));`

Comment: @KevinSmith If I log connection itself I get something like this: [code](https://codeshare.io/50qdAn)

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follows, so in case of any errors related to db connection you will get error message

```
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/dbname');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//on DB error
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error:'));
```